# php session lost between pages

Tags: php, session

I have a script with session betwen few pages, every one has `session_start()` right after `<?php` no BOM.

Works great on my test server but on the production server I lost all session variables and their values, `register_globals` are `off`.

Furtermore in FF I lost session on 4th page and in Chrome in 2th page, any ideas?

Will gladly take all hints.

-- 
On IE works great

--
Looks like the session is there all the time only variabels die (`var_dump` gives `array(0)`). I did `session_write_close()` but with no result

Comment: Ensure the session id gets passed and you always use the same session name. That's all you need to ensure. Normally users are running into cookie related problems when they ask questions similar to yours.

Comment: Anything in `error_log`?

Comment: Instead of guessing, you should create yourself a checklist, and then check one point after the other.

Comment: Problem solved, `session_name` was nessesary on this server to work properly

Comment: @user1113235 It's ok to answer your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the `session.save_path` is writable for the webserver.